# How to invert a list for a specific range for entire list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Consider the following list

```
    [[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6],[7,7,7]......]
```

I would like to replace the order every Nth rows:

```
    5 5 5 
    4 4 4 
    7 7 7 
    6 6 6
```

The general idea is from a list of 200 lines  take 20 lines and reverse the order list [0:20:-1] and continue this until list is done, thus only possible 10 times:

```
for i in range(length-1):
    tobeflipped=num[:20:-1]
    num=num[20:]
for i in tobeflipped:
    f.write(''.join(str([d for d in i]).strip('[]').replace (',','')+'\n'))
```

The output is kind of correct however it repeats the output more than 200 lines (it is almost  800 lines). I can't see how to correct it.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be doing matrix math? If so, try looking at NumPy/SciPy which does exactly that :) It's much more high level than raw python lists

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. First, is the vertical/matrix display part of your questions, or not? Is it just about swapping the order of some of the elements within the list?

Comment: no its for image manipulation of ppm files. trying to horizontal flip by using lists or by creating functions, with out using built in python modules (which is would make it too easy)

Comment: So you want us to help you with a problem, but won't accept a simple solution?

Comment: ppm file is placed in a list[]. then taking the length (north to south  of the picture which is 20 lines and reversing the slice, then continue with the rest of the lines. the picture dimension (20x10) thus 200 lines.

Comment: you want to print 7,7,7 and then 6,6,6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My version changes your list inplace:

```
def block_reverse(lst, blocksize):
    for i in range(blocksize-1, len(lst), blocksize):
        if i<blocksize:
            lst[:blocksize]=lst[blocksize-1::-1]
        else:
            lst[i-blocksize+1:i+1] = lst[i:i-blocksize:-1]

m=[[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6],[7,7,7]]
block_reverse(m, 2)
print m
```

Finding out how it achieves the reversing exactly is an exercise for you :)

Comment: my code on the bottom of the post does the reversing but it just repeats longer then it should.

Comment: This requires a lot more thinking than mine.  Kudos to you for actually figuring out where the blocks start and end, although it will only work on list-like objects, not arbitrary iterators. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @mgilson, one more bonus that is good with in place changing, is that you spare the expensive `append` operation. So, this code is one order faster.

Comment: @Oz123 -- I believe that.  `append` isn't terribly slow (it's O(1)), but method lookup in general is a bit slow.  I might actually get faster code with `block += [elem]` or `block[-1:-1] = [elem]` since those should avoid method lookup (you could test it and see).  But, mine has the overhead of creating a generator and mulitple lists which can be a bit pricey I suppose.  I generally try to avoid in-place changing of objects inside functions as it can lead to bugs which are tricky to track down.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a generator:

```
def revsec(blocksize,lst):
    block = []
    for i,elem in enumerate(lst):
        if i % blocksize:
            block.append(elem)
        else:
            #python 3.3 note -- use `yield from block[::-1]` instead.
            for item in block[::-1]:  #reversed(block) might be better here
                yield item

            block = [elem]

    #yield any stragglers.        
    for item in block[::-1]:        #reversed(block) might be better here too
        yield item

a = range(200)
print list(revsec(20,a))
```

This has a few advantages.  First, the input "list" doesn't have to be a list.  It can be any iterator.  This also returns an iterator, so it really only needs to cache `blocksize` elements at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6],[7,7,7]]

for e, u in zip(num[::2], num[1::2]):
   print ' '.join(["%s" %i for i in u])
   print ' '.join(["%s" %i for i in e])
```